# get no of new users per month using sql and python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

Database -

```
    sender_id  timestamp
    abc        1662367190.3912148
    hsj        1662367190.3912363
    hsj        1662367190.3912811
    kfj        1662367190.8625183
    abc        1662367190.8732119
    ytf        1662367190.8732183
    plw        1662367190.873222
    hsj        1662367190.8732316
    pws        1662367190.880536
    pws        1662367209.621818
    dlj        1662367209.6316075
    lsf        1662367209.641992
    lsf        1662367209.642001
    qwe        1662367209.653683
```

I tried:

python

```
def new_users():
    sql_query = """SELECT COUNT(SENDER_ID), DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TO_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP)) FROM 
                    EVENTS GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TO_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP))"""
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    newusers = dict(cursor.fetchall())
    return newusers
```

Data is in timestamp format

I need to return no of new users every month

Desired output - {nov2022:45, dec2022:82, jan2023:29, feb2023:9, march2023: 91}

The count should not include a user who has appeared at any given point before that particular month

Comment: 1) Use proper timestamp not epoch. 2) Define what a *new user* is? Is that they have never be seen at any point in time or not seen before in that month? 3) Define why you think the above is not working. Add expected output and actual output . **ADD information as update to question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can do this with two levels of aggregation: first compute the first connection date of each user, then aggregate by month:

```
select date_trunc('month', to_timestamp(min_timestamp)) month_timestamp,
    count(*) cnt_new_users
from (
    select min(timestamp) min_timestamp
    from events 
    group by sender_id
) t
group by 1
```